# silverlight for wp7: TextBlock: text with different text-align in same line

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to have a TextBlock element that contains two seperate strings, both in a single line. One is aligned to the left edge of the TextBlock, one to the right edge.

In HTMl&CSS I would do it like this:

```
<div id="TextBlock">
  <span style="float:left;display:block">align:left</span>
  <span style="float:right;display:block">align:right</span>
  <span style="clear:both"></span>
</div>
```

Here both Texts *align:right* and *align:left* are shown in the same line.

Is there a possibility to do this in XAML as well?

Comment: Have you tried? If you put two TextBlocks into a Grid container with the text alignment you want, it should work.

Comment: so I'll have two TextBlocks in one Grid field? OK, havn't tried that...

Comment: It's simplistic of course, it won't handle overlaps. If you want a proper layout, you'll have to specify columns, as per @Ku6opr's answer.

Comment: Yeah, right! I don't have overlaps, so this worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Put `TextBlocks` inside a `Grid` control into different `Columns`. You must specify how `TextBlocks` will trim if `Grid` width is less that `TextBlocks` total width. Set `Auto`, `*` or `number*` for this in different combinations:

```
 <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="text1" TextAlignment="Left" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="text2" TextAlignment="Right" />
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

jv42's comment-answer worked fine for me:

> Have you tried? If you put two TextBlocks into a Grid container with the text alignment you want, it should work. – jv42